# leaflet polyline, how to add a property to the point?

Tags: leaflet, geojson, polyline

I`m trying to use polyline from Leaflet. First, I draw some polylines programmatically, and then I need to read the resulting data (after modifications done by the user). The problem is I would like to assign some property to the polyline point to distinguish between them at the saving moment. When the polyline is modified (changed point position/ added new points), points become recreated, so if I assign properties to points - they become lost at the modification moment. How can I solve it?